# How to undo folder redirection policy settings on a Windows 7 in a Windows Server 2003 environment

Tags: windows-server-2003

All users in the company I work for are configured to use roaming profiles. One specific user has asked me to remove roaming profiles for her. There is a folder redirection policy in place and it is applied to a group that all users are members of.

I want to disable folder redirection for this user without affecting any of the other users in the company.
My steps:

1. Remove user from group
2. Create an OU and a group to undo folder redirection policy settings
3. Make user a member of that group
4. Configure same folder redirection setting but with the "Redirect the folder back to the local user profile location when policy is removed" option enabled
5. Link new policy to new OU and set security so it only applies to the new group created in step 2 with No Override
6. Set security on original policy so the new group created in step 2 has Deny Read and Apply Group Policy permissions
7. Logoff the user and restart her computer

This does not seem to work well for me. Maybe I missed a step or did something before or after I should have done it.

Any help on this matter will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a GPO with loopback or merge settings. This user an still stay in her regular OU. Just set the GPO permissions to only apply to her but read for everyone else.